# Responsive sidebar images don't show on resize

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my sidebar : https://jsfiddle.net/8ejwykwv/1/

The issue is that on small screens, sidebar completely disappears. Whereas what I'm trying to  achieve is on a certain screen size, have only images displayed. example : Home icon without Home text. And on a very small screen have only a button that slides the sidebar left and right or top-down.

I tried using

```
 @media(min-width:42em){
     .sidebar{
        width:4em;
     }
 }
```

But I'm pretty much lost.
I understand media queries and what can be done with them, but I'm not sure how to manipulate with my sidebar and topbar so that I have like fa-fa bars that on click will show more than just an image.

Link as a reference to what I have been trying:

[This link](https://codepen.io/wideckop/pen/ZOgOPq) and/or [This example](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/djjrN)

Any help is appreciated. I'm a beginner so I apologize in advance if it may be simple thing. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just fix the width in sidebar class:

```
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    width:160px !important;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;  
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
    background-color: black

}
```

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/c8h5ede7/8/

**EDIT**
You can also try this solution

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 42em) {
    .sidebar{
        width:8em !important;
     }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c8h5ede7/12/

Comment: Thank you,But fixing the width doesn't make it responsive and on smaller screens a button to show..